# In AWS Cognito, what is the maximum user account limit per user-pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We need to know that the maximum user-account we can create in 
 single user-pool (in Cognito) and what is the cost if we want to increase that limit.

We have also tried to find the answer but not found any.

Answer (score 7):

The soft limit (changable) of maximum number of users per user pool in AWS Cognito is: 40,000,000.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html

To request an increase of default quotas: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html

**Update: 2020, Dec:** Limit increased from 20m to 40m.

Comment: The limit is now  doubled to 40 million.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no limit for users. Limits are in other way.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html